# How to make apache treat query string as file name?

Tags: string, apache, mod-rewrite, replace, url-rewriting

I mirrored a site to local server with wget and the file names locally look like this:

```
comments
comments?id=123
```

Locally these are static files that show unique content.
But when I access second file in browser it keeps showing content from file `comments` and appends the query string to it `?id=123` so it is not showing content from file `comments?id=123`

It loads the correct file if I manually encode the `?` TO `%3F` in browser window and I type:

`comments%3Fid=123`

Is there a way to fix this ? Maybe make apache stop treating `?` as query separator and treat it as file name character ? Or make an URL rewrite and change `?` into `%3F` ?

Edit: Indeed too many problems caused by `?` in file name and requests. I ended up using the wget option `--restrict-file-names=windows` that would convert `?` into an `@` when saving file name.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "don't do that."

The longer answer is that ? is a reserved character in URLs, using it as a part of a filename is going to cause problems forever, and the recommended solution is to pick a different character to use in those filenames. There are many to choose from - just avoid ? & @ and # and you'll probably be fine.

If you insist on keeping the file name (or if you don't have an option) try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule (.*) $1%%3F%1 [NE]
```

However, this is going to fire *any* time you have a query string, which is likely not what you want.

Comment: I think matching all `?` is not a problem since I know all files in that directory will always be static. However `$1%%3F%1` shows `bad request` and `$1\%3F%1` `Server Error`, anything else I can try ?